# Are there zoos in Sharn/Eberron and if so what animals would they have?

Tags: dnd-5e, druid, wild-shape, animals, eberron

I'm currently playing a Warforged Druid in an Eberron Campaign, and our characters are currently located in the City of Sharn, and are likely to be stuck there for some time.

I've opted to go with the Circle of the Moon primarily for the Circle Forms Wild Shape capability.

#### [Wild Shape](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/classes#WildShape)

> As an action, you can magically assume the shape of a beast ***that you have seen before*** (emphasis mine) twice per short rest.

**As a fundamentally urban-bound druid, are there any canon (or even semi-canon) locations in Sharn where my character could personally observe animals such as a [Dynonichus](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/deinonychus) in relative safety?**

Or more generally, where could they go to observe any of the CR 1 animals that are available such as [Dire Wolf](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/dire-wolf) or [Brown Bear](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/brown-bear).

Otherwise, the character is stuck with [Giant Spider](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/giant-spider) as his only 'combat-ready' Wildshape form. He was lucky enough to almost be killed by one so he's got that going for him, which is nice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### There are zoos in Sharn, which house exotic monsters

In the D&D 3.5 sourcebook *Sharn, City of Towers*, p. 176, the existence of zoos is mentioned:

> In a world full of bizarre and magical creatures, even the great cities are not free from the depredations of monsters. In fact, the bustle and chaos of a cosmopolitan environment allows some monsters to move around more freely than they could in smaller settlements, and the ready availability of easy prey attracts certain types of monsters to the city streets. All sorts of monsters may appear in cities at one time or another—ogre mercenaries may wander the streets unmolested as long as they remain on their best behavior, wild bulettes **captured and displayed in zoos**, demons conjured in the shrouded inner chambers of an evil temple, or golems constructed in the hidden depths of a school of wizardry. In Sharn, situated directly above several layers of ancient ruins, monsters occasionally wander up from the Depths.

It goes on to note that dinosaurs (the swindlespitter, in particular) could be encountered as servants of the city's humanoid inhabitants. The deinonychus is not mentioned specifically, and it is noted that creatures like this in the streets without their human owners are likely to cause concern.

In Eberron, the deinonychus is referred to as the *carver*. According to the D&D 3e *Eberron Campaign Setting*), p. 123, the carver is used primarily as a war mount. The D&D 4e *Eberron Campaign Guide*, p. 41, notes that they were originally domesticated by the Talenta halflings.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that since carvers are such traditional mounts for halflings, and Sharn is so cosmopolitan, there is *definitely* some stables somewhere that you could meet some. *Sharn, City of Towers* also mentions a “Little Plains” district, and while stables aren’t mentioned explicitly, it’s mentioned as the area where you can find “exotic services” from Talenta (the example is a traditional practice wherein a weary warrior has scented oil rubbed into their hair while relaxing on couches). If they’ve got more unusual stuff, they’re certain to have something as mundane as stables